# How to set custom headers for every request on Azure App Service?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, http-headers, azure-web-app-service

I want to set up a custom header to each request on my site that is deployed on Azure. How can I do it via Azure?

Answer (score 0):

@silent is right and we can use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/rewrite-http-headers. Unfortunately, it is a hard way. I will try to find an easier solution, for example setting headers in Web.config or etc.

Comment: Did you ever find another way?

Comment: @NathanBubna As I remember I couldn't find another way.